# Finding files within date range suffix

Tags: bash, date

I have list of log files which names has date suffix:

```
mylog.2014-01-01.gz
mylog.2014-01-02.gz
........
mylog.2014-03-04.gz
```

I have a start and end date, for example 2014-02-01 -> 2014-02-04. Using bash on linux script I want to find files with name matching date range. So I want to get files:

```
mylog.2014-02-01
mylog.2014-02-02
mylog.2014-02-03
mylog.2014-02-04
```

I can not depend on

```
find /path -type f -newer $startFile -not -newer $endFile mylog*gz
```

because mylog.2014-02-01 can be modified on **2014-02-01 23:59** or **2014-02-02 00:01**

Comment: You may not be able to do this in Bash with something as simple as the `find` command, and Bash isn't too good at date handling. You're better off using Python or Perl to do this. Would you like a Perl solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
START_DATE=$(date -d '2014-02-01 01' '+%s')
END_DATE=$(date -d '2014-02-04 01' '+%s')
IFS=.
for i in mylog.*.gz; do
    fname=($i)
    d=$(date -d "${fname[1]} 01" '+%s')
    if (($d > $START_DATE && $d < $END_DATE)); then
        echo "Found file: $i"
    fi
done
```

Thanks to @kojiro for the IFS and glob ideas.

Comment: I think there are some typos here. Pretty sure `i` isn't a command. Also, iterating over the output of a command substitution is dangerous if that command substitution doesn't guarantee a particular type of whitespace handling. `find` doesn't. You should use globs instead. (All that said, algorithmically this seems a sensible approach.)

Comment: How about `IFS=.; for i in mylog.*.gz; do f=($i); d=$(date -d "${f[1]} 01" '+%s'); …`? – eliminate a bunch of subshells, dangerous wordsplits and relatively expensive operations.

Comment: I have created funtion getLogs() where first argument is directory. Can I assing result of running command twice to variable in one line liek: result=$(getLogs /dir1 2014-01-12 2014-01-22) $(getLogs /dir2 2014-01-12 2014-01-22)

Comment: @KrzyH Do you want the outputs seperated by a newline? I would do: `result="$(getLogs /dir1 2014-01-12 2014-01-22)\n$(getLogs /dir2 2014-01-12 2014-01-22)`